# removing a column from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a multidimentional array in javascript like this

```
Arr[i].ProductId
Arr[i].ProductName
Arr[i].ProductCode
Arr[i].ProductDescription
Arr[i].ProductOrigin
Arr[i].ProductInfo
```

Arr is populated with data
when everything is done with Arr,I want to have another array without (ProductCode,ProductOrigin,ProductInfo) columns.

I have done this

```
var list2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Arr));
for (i in list2) {
    delete list2[i].ProductCode;
    delete list2[i].ProductOrigin;
    delete list2[i].ProductInfo;
}
```

this is iterating through the array. is it possible to remove the Columns without iterating? or what is the better solution for that?

Comment: No, there is no method to delete parts of an object array in constant time.

Comment: Where is the multi dimensional part of your array? Looks like you just have an object array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the list to get the new version of every element. Another way to do this is using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const list2 = Arr.map(({ ProductCode, ProductOrigin, ProductInfo, ...e }) => e);
```

Comment: The Map function doesn't work on Edge